# Cant call function from within object after saving with SharedObject

Tags: function, actionscript-3, return

tl;dr --- I'm trying to create an object and have the name of a function inside that object, then save the object, load it later, and be able to call the function e.g. **myFunction on the Main.as**, based on the obj.fun() where **obj.fun = myFunction** or **obj.fun = "myFunction"**;

I create a global variable

```
var master = {};
```

I create an object thusly

```
createMyObject():Object
{
  obj = {
  name:"myObject",
  fun:myFunctionInMain
  }
return obj
}
```

I then push the obj into an Array

```
master.myArray.push(obj);
```

Then I save

```
save.data.master = master;
```

Then I load

```
master = save.data.master;
```

Then I trace my object name like this:

```
trace(master.myArray[0].name) // output is correct "myObject" so the save and load worked
```

but when I call the function

```
master.myArray[0].fun();
```

it says value is not a function.

This works fine until I save then load... It's as if it isn't saving the function inside the object.... so I tried to put the function in quotes, inside the object and it saves the string, but I can't figure out how to call the function from that after I save it.

I've tried

```
master.myArray[0][master.myArray[0]]() // didn't work
```

I've tried

```
var fun:String = master.myArray[0]fun;
master.myArray[0][fun]() // didn't work
```

I've tried

```
var fun:Function = master.myArray[0].fun;
fun(); // didn't work
```

I thank you very much for any insight here... I've been calling functions from within objects for a while now, but now that I want to save and load, I am seeing this isn't going to work like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it.

```
var functionName:String = master.myArray[0].fun; // where master was saved in save.data.master 

var newFun:Function = this[functionName];
newFun();
```

Seems to work.